# Dividing a huge for loop using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to create a graph and since there are 2600 nodes and I have to iterate through each node to create an edge, my for loop is running for almost 6 million times. Therefore, I am trying to do multiprocessing to make this faster. Now what I want, is to create 20 processes and divide the 6 million lines between them. I wrote this following code, but it doesn't work.

```
from igraph import *
from multiprocessing import Process    

def generate_edges(call_record_dict):
    for index, key in enumerate(call_record_dict):
        for index2, key2 in enumerate(call_record_dict):
            if(key!=key2):
                if(call_record_dict[key]==call_record_dict[key2]):
                    if(g.are_connected(index, index2) is False):
                        g.add_edges((index,index2))

def generate_graph(call_record_dict):
    g=Graph()
    g.add_vertices(len(call_record_dict))
    for i in range(20):
        p = Process(target=generate_edges, args=(call_record_dict))
        p.start()
```

I've tried using Pool.

```
pool = Pool(processes=20)
pool.map(generate_edges,call_record_dict)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

This doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: What you mean is `Process(target=generate_edges, args=(call_record_dict,))`, but even that won't work because you make no distinction between different runs of `generate_edges()`.

Comment: Yeah,sorry, I fixed the argument path. How do I make distinction between the runs?

Comment: I am assuming that `call_record_dict` is a dictionary.  You could define 20 separate dictionaries based on that dictionary.  For example, you could say `keys = call_record_dict.keys()`.  Then in `for i in range(20):` you would need to define a smaller dictionary based on `keys` and `call_record_dict`.  For example, `small_dict = {key: call_record_dict[key] for key in keys[(i - 1) * (len(keys) / 20):i * (len(keys) / 20)]}`. You could then use `small_dict` as the args instead of `call_record_dict`.  You will probably come across errors, unexpected behavior, etc; but that's the general idea.

Comment: Unless you have 20 CPUs/cores at your disposal, is that going to speed anything up?

Comment: I am going to run it from a server, so it would. Right now, I just need to divide this into n processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values in the call_record_dict are hashable and are unique for each connection, you might try a different approach.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools as it

matches = defaultdict(list)

for index, value in enumerate(call_record_dict.values()):
    matches[value].append(index)

for values in matches.values():
    for index1, index2 in it.combinations(values, 2):
        g.add_edge((index1, index2))
        g.add_edge((index2, index1))
```

Run time should be O(n), where n in the length of the dictionary, rather than O(n^2).

Comment: Thanks. The first for loop worked but I got errors in the second for loop. Suppose my defaultdict looks like this. `defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {17: ['abc', 'def','cvb'], 2: ['xyz','hbf'], 3: ['dfg', 'cbn']})`. Now, what I want is send the first character of values to another function in an iterative manner, i.e i want to call generate_edges(a,d,c), then generate_edges(x,h) and so on. Now, `for index in matches.values():
  print index[0][:1]` gives me the first characters of each index[0] i.e, a,x,d,b. But i can't iterate among the indexes without a nested for loop. Can you please help?

Comment: I presumed only two indexes per each call.  I edited the answer to handle multiple indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from igraph import *
import  multiprocessing as mp

def generate_edges(call_record_dict):
    for index, key in enumerate(call_record_dict):
        for index2, key2 in enumerate(call_record_dict):
            if(key!=key2):
                if(call_record_dict[key]==call_record_dict[key2]):
                    return (index, index2)



def generate_graph(call_record_dict):
    g=Graph()
    g.add_vertices(len(call_record_dict))
    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    for index, ret in pool.map(generate_edges, call_record_dict):
        # ret = (index, index2)
        if(g.are_connected(ret) is False):
            g.add_edges((ret))
```

I dont have igraph and never used it so sorry this is not fully tested

Comment: It gives the following error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jan_seven.py", line 195, in <module>
    generate_graph(call_record_dict)
  File "jan_seven.py", line 152, in generate_graph
    for index, ret in pool.map(generate_edges, call_record_dict):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str